# Why is it necessary to call ctx.writeAndFlush when using the MessageToByteEncoder

Tags: netty

I am implementing as SIP server on top of Netty and everything was working fine using Netty 3.x. However I decided to upgrade to Netty 4 because of the well defined threading model but things have changed a lot and I am lost. My initial question (I got most of it working, but it doesn't quite make sense to me just yet) is regarding the `MessageToByteEncoder` and why I have to call `ctx.writeAndFlush` myself.

The bootstrap:

```
private void createTCPListeningPoint() {
    this.serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();

    this.serverBootstrap.group(this.bossGroup, this.workerGroup)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(final SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    final ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new SipFrameDecoder(Protocol.TCP));
                    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new SipMessageEncoder());
                    pipeline.addLast("handler", NettyNetworkStack.this.sipHandler);
                }
            });
    // .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
    // .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000)
    // .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
    // .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
}
```

(the bind operation takes place later and is not shown here)

Since the incoming pipeline is working (the decoder and handler is being called as they should) the only interesting part is the `SipMessageEncoder`, which is super simple and the code for it is found below. Also note that I have been playing around with the various options but as suspected, I haven't found any combination that changes this behavior.

The encoder:

```
public final class SipMessageEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<SipMessage> {

@Override
protected void encode(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final SipMessage msg, final ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
    final Buffer b = msg.toBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.getReadableBytes(); ++i) {
        out.writeByte(b.getByte(i));
    }
    out.writeByte(SipParser.CR);
    out.writeByte(SipParser.LF);
    // ctx.writeAndFlush(out);
}
```

}

The `SipMessage` and `SipParser` etc are taken from my other opensource project pkts.io but is not really relevant to this question. Just know that the `SipMessage.toBuffer()` essentially just spits a raw `byte[]` which I then am transferring to the `ByteBuff` as passed in by Netty.

The above code does not work unless I do `ctx.writeAndFlush(out)`. However, I thought, as in Netty 3, that the purpose of this slightly higher-level encoder is to shield me from these details. Step debugging through the code the `ByteBuf` is written to the `ctx` but not flushed, which I guess is the reason for it not showing up on the socket. So, my questions are simply:

- Why do I have to call `ctx.writeAndFlush` myself when I am using the `SipMessageEncoder`. The `NumberEncoder` in the Factorial example doesn't do this and looking through the HTTP codecs I couldn't see that it did that either so obviously I am missing something obvious.
- Also, the `ByteBuf` is being written to the context but is never flushed so when will it be? I tried to push a lot of traffic through a single TCP connection (using sipp) to see if that would eventually force a flush but nope, nothing shows up ever.

Btw, I also tried to use the `MessageToMessageEncoder` and allocate the ByteBuf through the context and add it to the `List` but the same result.

Btw2 – I am using Netty 4.0.10.Final

Thanks,

/Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you call flush() somewhere else when writing a message to the channel?

> "..you must be very careful not to forget to call ctx.flush() after writing something. Alternatively, you could use a shortcut method writeAndFlush()"

Actually you don't need to call write() in the SipMessageEncoder since the message will be written by the parent MessageToByteEncode. You just need to call flush() if it hasn't been done before.

Comment: Hi Igor,

No, I do not call flush and it doesn't actually help since I am not writing anything myself. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the usage of the MessageToByteEncoder but I was under the impression that I convert one object to another (in this case ByteBuf) and at some point later in the pipeline it will get written and flushed. I am sure I am just missing something extremely obvious. If I do ctx.writeAndFlush on the bytebuf it works but then I don't really understand the point of the MessageToByteEncoder.

Comment: Hi again Igor, actually I think I understand what you mean. No, I don't call flush in my SipMessageEncoder and perhaps there is where the problem is. I'll give that a go and if that works then thanks for getting me on the right track! Very much appreciated. I will update as soon as I have tried it but first, actual work work :-)

Comment: You see, all messages, written to the channel, reside in output buffer until you call flush(). The main usage scenario is the following: you write messages to the channel followed by flush(). Each message is serialized by the MessageToByteEncoder. It is not required to call write() here. After final flush() all messages will be written to the line. If you don't call flush() before you can do it in the SipMessageEncoder.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. Even though I read that myself several times I was so focused on the encoder that I completely overlooked this obvious thing. Even the factorial example does this but for some reason I just didn't add two and two together. Thanks for your patience Igor, very much appreciated.